# My friend has a PE world and she wants to put it on my Windows 10 minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend has a PE world and she wants to put it on my Windows 10. Would there be anyway to do this

Comment: I think it depends on how the files are stored. First question is, is the PE world on android or IOS? If its on android, then I would connect the phone to the PC and try and copy the files into the .minecraft folder on your PC. If they dont save them in the same format or if the phone runs IOS then AFAIK, you are SOL.

Comment: Hi Sonny, welcome to Arqade! In order to effectively answer this question we are going to need additional information from you. Specifically, what version of PE does your friend have, and are you able to get the files onto your windows 10 machine?